# Swedish message shown in javascript confirm box showing question mark(?)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function ConfirmGroupDelete() {
            if (confirm('Är du säker på att du vill ta bort alla händelser i gruppen Test3?')) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

I want swedish message when button clicked but it showing following.

[image]

Please help me how will I solve it?

Comment: character set mismatch. make sure that the charset used to write your page in is the charset that the html tells the browser it should be rendered as.

Comment: Ensure that: 1. Your HTML is being served using the charset you think it is (UTF-8 or whatever). 2. Your HTML file is actually written in that charset. 3. That your JavaScript is being served using the charset you think it is (UTF-8 or whatever). 4. That the JavaScript file is actually written in that charset. 5. In theory, it's okay if the HTML and JavaScript files are in different charsets; in practice, I'd use the same one for both kinds. :-)

Comment: H&auml;ndelsedatum fr.o.m.=Händelsedatum t.o.m. I don't know how they are generating such string. I am beginner on that.

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder sir for your answer. I just started development with Javascript and Jquery. I don't have much more knowledge on it.

Answer (score -1):

```
function ConfirmGroupDelete() {
            var labelMsg = document.createElement("Label"); // create Label dynamically
            labelMsg.innerHTML = "&Auml;r du s&auml;ker p&aring; att du vill ta bort alla h&auml;ndelser i gruppen Test3?";

            if (confirm(labelMsg.innerHTML)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
}
```

Now I did like this way. I have found corresponding HTML code of swedish word and replace it into my message. Then I have created a label dynamically and set that message into the innerHTML property of the Label and then shown in the confirm box. If I direct put the message into confirm("") then it shows as normal text(&Amul is showing). I don't know what is the reason behind it, If anybody has good suggestion, you can tell me.

Comment: Is there any better way to do that please tell me? I don't know, it is better to do or not.